# Jhipster-generator error on production profile

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm Trying to run my app in production profile, i'm using jhipster-generator for spring-boot app and angular. The app only run the footer and the background but the rest of the aplication nope, The error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myAppdue to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:17716
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:27870
        at n (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:27343)
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:27655
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:9:4997
        at r (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:18164)
        at f (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:9:4845)
        at rt (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:9:6774)
        at a (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:25413)
        at ie (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:25723)
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'myApp'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DdigitalBlogApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A17716%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A27870%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A27343)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A27655%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A9%3A4997%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A18164)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20f%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A9%3A4845)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20rt%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A9%3A6774)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A25413)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ie%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A25723)
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:17716
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:27870
        at n (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:27343)
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:27655
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:9:4997
        at r (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:18164)
        at f (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:9:4845)
        at rt (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:9:6774)
        at a (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:25413)
        at ie (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:25723)
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'myApp'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DdigitalBlogApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A17716%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A27870%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A27343)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A27655%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A9%3A4997%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A18164)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20f%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A9%3A4845)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20rt%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A9%3A6774)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A25413)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ie%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fvendor-7004bf12ca.js%3A8%3A25723)
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:17716
        at http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:9:5273
        at r (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:18164)
        at f (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:9:4845)
        at rt (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:9:6774)
        at a (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:25413)
        at ie (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:25723)
        at re (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:8:24962)
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:13:25627)
        at p (http://localhost:8080/app/vendor-7004bf12ca.js:2:8692)
```

what can it be ?

Comment: please tell me the your node version

Comment: Have you run the prod built war locally using java -jar ?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to something you changed in index.html because JHipster uses gulp to inject scripts and css into it when building for production. Compare your current version with the one you archived in git at project generation time.

Comment: Correct answer, but now i have other problem, some javascript files custom that i downloaded and added into the project, those files aren't correctly injected into the vendor, any ideas ? the console gave me the same error console but now i know what module is failing, but i don't know how to solve that problem

Comment: If my answer is correct, please consider accepting it. I already answered to this question on stackoverflow, the problem is the bower.json files of your dependencies that do not declare main property correctly. You got to use overrides property in you project bower.json.